# Matching text patterns relaxing contraints with admitted character substitutions

Tags: regex, text, language-agnostic

Suppose I've to match some patterns in an input text. Let the pattern be

```
password
```

I want to match all inputs that match with my pattern but admitting a predefined set of *character substitution*, say:

```
1. a -> @
2. e -> 3
3. o -> 0
4. i -> !
5. s -> $
```

Staying my example, I'd like all the following inputs to be successfully matched against my `password` pattern: `p@ssword`, `p@$sword`, `pa$$w0rd`, and so on.

My main question is *how to do it*, but narrowing it down:

1. is regex the *right* instrument to do that?
2. how can I define an admitted *set of substitutions* that regex matching should take into account?
3. is this a pretty common question that I've overlooked?
4. what is a concise way (i.e. just defining *once* the substitutions without having to repeat them for every admitted pattern) to achieve this for multiple patterns?

Note that `password` was just a *convenient* word containing several possible replacements; my problem does not want to deal with security at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the substitution always is a single character (or one single characters between multiple choices), you can use a character class :

```
p[a@][s$][s$]w[o0]rd
```

If it can be multiple characters, you have to use alternations :

```
pass(w|\/\/)ord
```

You could define a map/dictionary of original characters to possible substitutions in the language of your choice and use that to transform an input into a pattern :

```
1. a -> [a@]
2. e -> [e3]
3. o -> [o0]
4. i -> [i!]
5. s -> [s$]
6. w -> (w|\/\/)

password -> p[a@][s$][s$](w|\/\/)[o0]rd
```

I think regex can be a good tool for that, but there are already existing tools that will test the strength of a password if that's what you're looking for. They account for common substitutions.

Maybe using [Levenshtein's distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) would also be useful to you if you want to forbid people from reusing a close password.

Comment: Thank you very much! I've just realized that I forgot a _key question_, that now I've added as question 4. Can you have a look at it please?

Comment: Yes, and it was not so hard to figure out, now that you make me think about it... :D thank you